# RequestError connecting two docker containers

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 3 containers in my docker compose: 2 webserver, 1 mongodb instance. Weather-service sends http request to Main-service, so in my docker configuration I linked that two containers. To reach main-service container from weather-service I use this address: http://main-service:3000
When I run: docker-compose up --build, I receive an error for connection.
weather-service dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

EXPOSE 4000

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn --pure-lockfile
ADD . /app

CMD ["yarn", "docker:start"]
```

main-service dockerfile

```
FROM node:8-alpine

EXPOSE 3000

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn --pure-lockfile
ADD . /app

CMD ["yarn", "docker:start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  main-service:
    build: main-service
    volumes:
      - .:/app/main-service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - ./main-service/.env
    networks:
      - app-network
    links:
      - weather-service

  weather-service:
    build: weather-service
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/forecast-data
    volumes:
      - .:/app/weather-service
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    env_file:
      - ./weather-service/.env
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    networks:
            - app-network
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

networks:
  app-network:
    external: true
```

This is the error which I receive:

> weather-service_1  | 0|index    | RequestError: Error: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.4:3000 weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at
>   new RequestError
>   (/app/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at Request.plumbing.callback
>   (/app/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at Request.RP$callback [as
>   _callback] (/app/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
>   mongodb_1          | 2018-01-06T13:46:19.281+0000 I STORAGE  [conn2]
>   createCollection: forecast-data.refreshtokens with generated UUID:
>   85c26f12-464f-4d69-a969-713acf634c6f weather-service_1  | 0|index    |
>   at self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at Request.emit
>   (events.js:211:7) weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at
>   Request.onRequestError (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at ClientRequest.emit
>   (events.js:211:7) weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at
>   Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9) weather-service_1 
>   | 0|index    |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13) weather-service_1  |
>   0|index    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) weather-service_1  |
>   0|index    |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>   weather-service_1  | 0|index    |     at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11) weather-service_1  | 0|index
>   |     at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

Comment: Did you create a network called `app-network` with `docker network create -d overlay app-network` ?

Comment: I created app-network with this command: docker network create app-network

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create the network within the compose stack file.

```
...
networks:
  app-network:
   driver: overlay
```

When you deploy the stack, Docker creates the given network.
On docker stack rm, Docker removes the network.

"ECONNREFUSED" maybe it requires communications over tcp.
Inside every service set the protocol option to tcp:

```
ports:
      - target: 3000
        published: 3000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
```

https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/understanding-docker-networking-drivers-use-cases/
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode

Comment: I modified compose file as you told me, now I receive this error when I run docker-compose up: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.main-service.ports is invalid: Invalid port "{'target': 3000, 'protocol': 'tcp', 'mode': 'ingress', 'published': 3000}", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
services.main-service.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or a number`

Comment: Use higher version of compose file
3.2 for example or higher, but keep in mind it require Docker Engine release: 17.04.0+

version: '3.2'
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2